# How to duplicate a record and specify a field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a sql statement to duplicate a record. My code works, but instead of copying the userId as I am doing at present, I want to set that value in the table. Here's my current code:

```
insert into tMyTable (userId, testDate, studentResponse)
select userId, testDate, studentResponse
from tMyTable 
where testId= 403
```

How can I  set the value of userId = 100 into the new record? I know I could easily do this by hand, but I have hundreds of records to change to the same userId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just bring 100 as userId, like this

```
insert into tMyTable (userId, testDate, studentResponse)
select 100 as userId, testDate, studentResponse
from tMyTable 
where testId= 403
```

Comment: With `INSERT INTO ... SELECT 100 as userId`, the `as userID` is optional in this case, since MySQL doesn't care what the columns are named in the `SELECT` clause. They certainly don't have to match the column names in the `INSERT` clause.